# Open the keyboard as numeric without adding InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Have been trying to implement a way for the soft keyboard to open first the Numeric key without saying that the EditText is numeric.

Is this possible ? if yes how ?

The editText btw are added dynamic, so can't do changes on XML files

Comment: build your own keyboard

Comment: You can set the input type to `Edittext` at runtime too. editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)

Comment: That will not work (first thing I try) the editText it will not accept letters if I do that way

Comment: Thats completely contradict your question . If you want to change the `InputType` during typing then use a `TextWatcher` . I am not sure if its a good approch or not .

Comment: Depents on the cases, for example lets say that that Edit text the first part are numbers and at the end letters, it makes perfect sense to start the keyboard as numeric so the user doesn't need to change to numeric then to letters again

BtW, sry if my english isn't lerfect :P I though that saying open first Numeric key without saying that is a numeric would imply what I need hehe :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set the editText such as `editTextField.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);`

it will open a keyboard with numeric first and let me choose the normal one and input letters also.

Answer (score 0):

You can set input type programmatically.

```
 EditText editText=new EditText(this);
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

**Edit**
You can use InputFilters

```
public class NumericInputFilter implements InputFilter {
String regEx = new String("^[0-9]+$")


@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart,
                           int dend) {
    if (source != null && !source.toString().matches(regEx) && !source.toString().equals( "")) {

        return "";
    }
    return source;
}
```

and on your editText, `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new NumericInputFilter()});`

Comment: Did you read the question that I asked ? Open the keyboard without saying that the EditText is numeric, doing that way, it will not accept letters only numbers.

Comment: you can remove the input filter when you don't need the restriction anymore.

Comment: Ty going to try it :D

Comment: Nop, keyboard with letter is open first, I need the keyboard with numbers to open at first